# JSP form clientside validation in Spring without JS

Tags: java, spring, forms, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to input form details into database using a JSP file, Spring, Tomcat, MS Access. I am not supposed to use Maven and JavaScript.

When I did this before using JSP and servlets, the pattern feature of HTML5 using regex patterns worked fine for my client side validation. As for eg, for Login Id,

```
   <input type="text" name="uid"
            pattern="/^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[_][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/" required>
```

worked fine. 
Now that I'm learning spring and trying to use the form tag, I am doing

```
    <form:input type="text" path="uid" />
```

which works fine, but I need the pattern validator for client side without using JavaScript.

Now whenever I try to add the pattern feature to this, like

```
    <form:input type="text" name="uid"
            pattern="/^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[_][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/" required/>
```

it reports an error which goes :

```
    type Exception report
    message /UserForm.jsp (line: 18, column: 61) equal symbol expected
    description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
```

Where am i going wrong?
I know I'll have to implement validator interface before I save the data into the database, I will get to it eventually. As of now, any help with this is highly appreciated.

I am new to spring, so it would be very kind of helpers to provide answers with explanation accompanying the workaround/solution code for the same.Thanks in advance.

Comment: why have not used [hibernate validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/) ?

Answer (score 0):

In case of JSP and Spring you should validate the form fields on the controller class and show errors on the form with additional error-fields:

```
<form:input path="user" id="userInput" />
<form:errors path="user" cssClass="error" />
```

In the controller class you validate your fields and if there are no errors you could save your data to the database otherwise you show errors on the form.

```
@PostMapping("/saveUser")
public String saveUser(@ModelAttribute("user") @Validated User user, 
    BindingResult result, Model model) {

  //custom validation
  //validator.validate(user, result);

  if (result.hasErrors()) {
     //if any errors, return back to fill out the form again
     return "userForm";
  }

  //save to DB and return success page
  return "success";
}
```

Validation could be standard and\or custom. There are a lot of good tutorials on the internet about Spring validation.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you have to change

```
<form:input type="text" name="uid" pattern="/^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[_][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/" required/>
```

to

```
<form:input type="text" name="uid" pattern="/^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[_][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/" required="required"/>
```

change `required` to `required="required"`